# How can I fetch last 30 days left joined with values from my own table?

Tags: mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm

In my Symfony2/Doctrine2 application, I have an entity, respectively a table in my database where I keep track of every user, if he or she has done a specific action on a specified day.

My table looks like that, let's call it `track_user_action`:

```
+---------+------------+
| user_id | date       |
+---------+------------+
|       1 | 2013-09-19 |
|       2 | 2013-09-19 |
|       1 | 2013-09-18 |
|       5 | 2013-09-18 |
|       8 | 2013-09-17 |
|       5 | 2013-09-17 |
+---------+------------+
```

I would like to retrieve a set of rows, where it shows the last 30 days, the corresponding weekday and if the specified user has an entry in this table, e.g. for user with `user_id = 1`:

```
+------------+--------------+-----------------+
| date       | weekday      | has_done_action |
+------------+--------------+-----------------+
| 2013-09-20 | Friday       | false           |
| 2013-09-19 | Thursday     | true            |
| 2013-09-18 | Wednesday    | true            |
| ...        |              |                 |
| 2013-08-20 | Tuesday      | false           |
+------------+--------------+-----------------+
```

I could think of a `LEFT JOIN` of a date-table and my `track_user_action`. But it seems senseless to create a special table just for the dates. MySQL should be able to handle the days, shouldn't it?

Approach:

```
SELECT
  # somehow retrieve last 30 days
  date AS date,
  DAYNAME(date) AS weekday,
  IF ... THEN has_done_action = true ELSE has_done_action = false
  # and according weekdays
LEFT JOIN track_user_action AS t
  ON t.date = # date field from above
WHERE t.user_id = 1
ORDER BY # date field from above
  DESC
LIMIT 0,30
```

My questions:

- What would be a good (My)SQL query that fetches this kind of result?
- In how far is this query implementable in Doctrine2 (I know for fact that Doctrine2 doesn't support all MySQL statements, e.g. `YEAR()` or `MONTH()`)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a working query statement for seven days (adapt query for 30 days accordingly):

```
SELECT
    d.date AS date,
    DAYNAME(d.date) AS weekday,
    IF(t.user_id IS NOT NULL, 'true', 'false') AS has_done_action
FROM (
    SELECT SUBDATE(CURDATE(), 1) AS date UNION
    SELECT SUBDATE(CURDATE(), 2) AS date UNION
    SELECT SUBDATE(CURDATE(), 3) AS date UNION
    SELECT SUBDATE(CURDATE(), 4) AS date UNION
    SELECT SUBDATE(CURDATE(), 5) AS date UNION
    SELECT SUBDATE(CURDATE(), 6) AS date UNION
    SELECT SUBDATE(CURDATE(), 7) AS date
    ) AS d
LEFT JOIN track_user_action t
ON t.date = d.date
```